# Flutter command prompt not working under Windows

Tags: flutter, command-prompt

I have downloaded and installed `flutter` under Windows. After that, I am unable to issue any `flutter` commands on the Windows command prompt.

Here are the things I have checked/tried so far:

- made sure to install Flutter in a directory where my user has write access
- made sure that the bin directory is added to the path
- uninstalled and reinstalled `flutter` two or three times

Do you have any idea what else can be the problem?

Comment: I think you should ask this question here: https://flutter.dev/community

Comment: After modifying `PATH` did you restart your computer? Ad `bin` @vsync: I am sure he didn't mean `/bin`. It is normal to have a local `bin` folder where the application builds, regardless of the target OS. However, I didn't install Flutter on my own, so no idea if this is the case here.

Comment: Improved title, edited the question to be a bit clearer, added tag "flutter".